# How to get a value from nested json in php

Tags: php, json

I am a beginner to JSON and i'm trying to get values from a json string. For example i want to read the first **"t":1443502800** and assing it to a variable ***$beginTime*** and the second **"t":1443790800** assigned to a variable ***$endTime***

```
{
  "op":"&",
  "c":[
       {
         "type":"date",
         "d":">=",
         "t":1443502800
       },
       {
         "type":"date",
         "d":"<",
         "t":1443790800
       }
     ],
  "showc":[true,true]
}
```

I would really appreciate any help :)

**Edit code**

```
foreach($rs2 as $record2)
    { 
      if( $record2->availability == '{"op":"&","c":[],"showc":[]}'){
        //skip, because the restriction date was not set for this attendance
      }
      else{
        //get the restriction date by making use of json                  
         $json_data = json_decode($record2->availability, true);
         echo $json_data['c'];
      }
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: What part are you getting stuck at? Have you looked at [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode)?

Comment: I use json_decode and this is my code:   $json_data = json_decode($record->availability, true); echo $json_data['c'][0];   this gives me an error - array to string convertion

Comment: @21stking You can't echo an array, that's why.

Comment: do $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json_data['c']); then your can see index and value.it will help debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't echo an array. You're trying to echo out `$json_data['c']`, which is an array. Either return it or echo out what you need. For instance to echo out the start time use `echo $json_data['c'][0]['t']`

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You should use json_decode without true in the second variable. Then you have objects (started with braces `{`) and arrays (started with square brackets `[`). You can then get the start and end times us

```
<?php
$string = '{
  "op":"&",
  "c":[
       {
         "type":"date",
         "d":">=",
         "t":1443502800
       },
       {
         "type":"date",
         "d":"<",
         "t":1443790800
       }
     ],
  "showc":[true,true]
}';
$json = json_decode($string);
echo "Start time: ".$json->c[0]->t;
echo "End time: ".$json->c[1]->t;
```

Here's an eval.in of it working - https://eval.in/441599

Comment: your first answered worked perfectly. All i need to do now is change a bit of code :)

Comment: I've added my first answer in again.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. The full call should be to

```
$beginTime = $json_data['c'][0]['t'];
```

since `$json_data['c'][0]` is the array:

```
array (
    "type" => "date",
    "d" => ">=",
    "t" => 1443502800
),
```

The `$endtime` can be obtained in a similar manner:

```
$endTime = $json_data['c'][1]['t'];
```

Comment: This is wrong, it doesn't turn it into an array, not entirely - https://eval.in/441602 Using a brace in json indicates an object, not an array.

Comment: The OP is setting the second parameter in json_decode to true. This results in an associative array not an object. From http://php.net/json_decode: "When [$assoc is] TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. "

Comment: Didn't have his code when I posted that, that's why it's important for people to include code in their question.